# Combining constraints with catch/3

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog, clpz

How do SICStus Prolog style attributed variables and the catch/throw Prolog exception handling mechanism interact?

Deep within the source code of [`library(clpz)`](https://github.com/triska/clpz), there's a piece of code I don't quite comprehend:

```
with_local_attributes(Vars, Goal, Result) :-
    catch((Goal,
           maplist(del_all_attrs, Vars),
           % reset all attributes, only the result matters
           throw(local_attributes(Result,Vars))),
          local_attributes(Result,Vars),
          true).
```

The auxiliary code of `del_all_attrs/1` is this:

```
del_all_attrs(Var) :-
    (  var(V)
    -> put_atts(V, -clpz(_)),
       put_atts(V, -clpz_aux(_)),
       put_atts(V, -clpz_relation(_)),
       % ... a lot more put_atts/2 goals follow ...
       put_atts(V, -clpz_gcc_vs(_)),
       put_atts(V, -clpz_gcc_num(_)),
       put_atts(V, -clpz_gcc_occurred(_))
    ;  true
    ).
```

Now, following the steps of these two predicates is not that hard,
but what effect does it all have for the involved variables and constraints?

The way I see it now the following happens:

1. `Goal` is executed; this may (and usually does) include the propagation of constraints.
2. All attributes are removed from variables in `Vars`; this effectively leaves all non-aliased variables as free variables, but preserves variable aliasing and ground values.
3. `throw/3` creates a copy of `Vars` and then undoes the effects of steps (1) and (2).
4. `catch/3` unifies the copy of `Vars` with the original `Vars`.
5. As a result all aliases and ground values that were present in `Vars` *after* the execution of `Goal` are "preserved", but all constraints are effectively reset. Execution resumes with waking some constraints by unifying `Vars` with the "returned" copy.

Am I on the right way?
And can I express this without `catch/3`, maybe by using `copy_term/3`?

Comment: So this is about Scryer too, right?

Comment: @false. I'm working with the sources that work on SICStus and I don't know about the details of the modified version of clp(Z) for Scryer Prolog. A quick glance tells me the two variants are not identical in this respect. Ideally, yes, all improvements of clp(Z) that I care about (including this one) should benefit all SICStus style systems.

Comment: @false. I am tuning a variant of clp(Z) on SICStus. I run exactly the same code on MI-Prolog (with varying, but growing success). I'm not interested in any kind of divergence in this matter.

Comment: Minor: This `Result` variable is a bit problematic (regardless of atvs) because there are implementations like SWI and IF that produce an error for `?- catch((X=a,throw(-b)),-X,true).` when they should answer `X = b`.

Comment: @false. Luckily, MI answers `X = b`:)